# Password validation with regexp

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to write password validation function with regexp and don't know how to do it.

The regex package provided by the standard API of the Go language is different to other languages.

Have someone an idea, how this regexp pattern should looks like?

The pattern should validate:

```
/*
 * Password rules:
 * at least 7 letters
 * at least 1 number
 * at least 1 upper case
 * at least 1 special character
 */
```

Comment: Expressing this in one regex is hard. I'd go with three regexes and one `len()` call instead.

Comment: Easily done with ordinary regex that use assertions. Otherwise, a simple series of character tests: length, digit char, upper alpha, punctuation.

Comment: Dear @M42 moderator, your "duplicate" question cannot apply with go regexp (http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/), using re2 ( http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax, an efficient, principled regular expression library). In the context of Go, this **is not a duplicate**.

Comment: @VonC: Sorry, I wasn't aware that go doesn't undaerstand lookaround. Vote for reopen.

Comment: @M42 no problem. I was surprised by that too (re2 missing backreferences and lookaround) at first with Go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The right regexp would be... no regexp here.

You can define a custom function that would validate the password, and combine it with other frameworks helping validating a field, like [mccoyst/validate](https://github.com/mccoyst/validate) (mentioned in this [discussion about parameter validation](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1r6hsv/how_do_you_all_go_about_validating_user_input/))

You also have [**go-validator/validator**](https://github.com/go-validator/validator) whic allows to define similar validations (but I would still use a custom validator instead of one or several regexps).

---

Note: [go regexp](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/) is based on **[re2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax)**, an efficient, principled regular expression library).

> So the major trade offs are **no back-references** for example: `(abc)\1` and **no matching look-behinds**.
>   In exchange you get **high speed regex**.

Comment: why not regexps, it is bad?

Comment: @zero_coding here it is, since you cannot easily express the constraints in *one* regexp. So... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/223634/3915 and http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: Why did go designer design different regex then other language? What is the reason?

Comment: @zero_coding performance reason. Adding lookahead/behind has been deemed too costly.

Comment: you are the master of Go. Thanks so much for explanation.

Comment: @zero_coding just learning here ;) For go-mastership level, see 
OneOfOne below.

Comment: @zero_coding I have edited the answer with a reference to the regex engine at the origin of regex in Go.

Comment: Hehe I'm humbled :) your answers usually go into a great more detail than mine

Comment: @OneOfOne well, I have always learned a lot from your answer. Which is good, considering the amount of Go programing I have to do (for work): https://github.com/VonC/gogitolite/commits?author=VonC. So thank you.

Comment: `regex` is perfectly fine an excels in scripting languages - but in `go` or any other compiled language, there's much more precise techniques at your disposal.

Answer (score 35):

That's actually impossible since Go's [regex](https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax) doesn't support backtracking.

However, it's easy to implement, a simple example:

```
func verifyPassword(s string) (sevenOrMore, number, upper, special bool) {
    letters := 0
    for _, c := range s {
        switch {
        case unicode.IsNumber(c):
            number = true
        case unicode.IsUpper(c):
            upper = true
            letters++
        case unicode.IsPunct(c) || unicode.IsSymbol(c):
            special = true
        case unicode.IsLetter(c) || c == ' ':
            letters++
        default:
            //return false, false, false, false
        }
    }
    sevenOrMore = letters >= 7
    return
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Building from a neighboring answer, I too wrote a helper function that works well for me. This one just assumes overall password length is satisfactory. Check out the following...

```
func isValid(s string) bool {
    var (
        hasMinLen  = false
        hasUpper   = false
        hasLower   = false
        hasNumber  = false
        hasSpecial = false
    )
    if len(s) >= 7 {
        hasMinLen = true
    }
    for _, char := range s {
        switch {
        case unicode.IsUpper(char):
            hasUpper = true
        case unicode.IsLower(char):
            hasLower = true
        case unicode.IsNumber(char):
            hasNumber = true
        case unicode.IsPunct(char) || unicode.IsSymbol(char):
            hasSpecial = true
        }
    }
    return hasMinLen && hasUpper && hasLower && hasNumber && hasSpecial
}
```

---

```
isValid("pass")     // false
isValid("password") // false
isValid("Password") // false
isValid("P@ssword") // false
isValid("P@ssw0rd") // true
```

- [Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/moPM-ITqsbU)

Answer (score 5):

Based on [**@OneOfOne**'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25840157/4408364) answer with some error message improvement

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
        "unicode"
    )

    func verifyPassword(password string) error {
        var uppercasePresent bool
        var lowercasePresent bool
        var numberPresent bool
        var specialCharPresent bool
        const minPassLength = 8
        const maxPassLength = 64
        var passLen int
        var errorString string

        for _, ch := range password {
            switch {
            case unicode.IsNumber(ch):
                numberPresent = true
                passLen++
            case unicode.IsUpper(ch):
                uppercasePresent = true
                passLen++
            case unicode.IsLower(ch):
                lowercasePresent = true
                passLen++
            case unicode.IsPunct(ch) || unicode.IsSymbol(ch):
                specialCharPresent = true
                passLen++
            case ch == ' ':
                passLen++
            }
        }
        appendError := func(err string) {
            if len(strings.TrimSpace(errorString)) != 0 {
                errorString += ", " + err
            } else {
                errorString = err
            }
        }
        if !lowercasePresent {
            appendError("lowercase letter missing")
        }
        if !uppercasePresent {
            appendError("uppercase letter missing")
        }
        if !numberPresent {
            appendError("atleast one numeric character required")
        }
        if !specialCharPresent {
            appendError("special character missing")
        }
        if !(minPassLength <= passLen && passLen <= maxPassLength) {
            appendError(fmt.Sprintf("password length must be between %d to %d characters long", minPassLength, maxPassLength))
        }

        if len(errorString) != 0 {
            return fmt.Errorf(errorString)
        }
        return nil
    }

    // Let's test it
    func main() {
        password := "Apple"
        err := verifyPassword(password)
        fmt.Println(password, " ", err)
    }
```

Comment: re error handling, better to have a custom error struct - and just append the reasons to say a slice of strings. Then have a String() renderer which will work out-of-the-box. But if someone wants to render this to html, as say a `<li></li>` list - the error struct has this info available to make this easy.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers seem to veer away from regex completely, which although helpful and likely higher performance, do not actually answer the OP's question. Here is my method for simple pass/fail testing of a password string, which is styled to suit my thinking. (Note that this checks length to be *at least* 7 characters, rather than the literal "7 letters" (exactly) requirement in the original question.) To me, this code is fairly simple and looks easier to read than doing `switch` statements or a bunch of `if` statements:

```
password := "Pa$$w0rd"
secure := true
tests := []string{".{7,}", "[a-z]", "[A-Z]", "[0-9]", "[^\\d\\w]"}
for _, test := range tests {
    t, _ := regexp.MatchString(test, password)
    if !t {
        secure = false
        break
    }
}
//secure will be true, since the string "Pa$$w0rd" passes all the tests
```

Answer (score 1):

Below it's my implementation of the above answers with custom messages and somehow twisting to them in a good way(performance aware codes).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    pass := "12345678_Windrol"

    // call the password validator and give it field name  to be known by the user, password, and the min and max password length
    isValid, errs := isValidPassword("Password", pass, 8, 32)
    if isValid {
        fmt.Println("The password is valid")
    } else {
        for _, v := range errs {
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    }

}

func isValidPassword(field, s string, min, max int) (isValid bool, errs []string) {
    var (
        isMin   bool
        special bool
        number  bool
        upper   bool
        lower   bool
    )

    //test for the muximum and minimum characters required for the password string
    if len(s) < min || len(s) > max {
        isMin = false
        appendError("length should be " + strconv.Itoa(min) + " to " + strconv.Itoa(max))
    }

    for _, c := range s {
        // Optimize perf if all become true before reaching the end
        if special && number && upper && lower && isMin {
            break
        }

        // else go on switching
        switch {
        case unicode.IsUpper(c):
            upper = true
        case unicode.IsLower(c):
            lower = true
        case unicode.IsNumber(c):
            number = true
        case unicode.IsPunct(c) || unicode.IsSymbol(c):
            special = true
        }
    }

    // append error
    appendError := func(err string) {
        errs = append(errs, field+" "+err)
    }

    // Add custom error messages
    if !special {
        appendError("should contain at least a single special character")
    }
    if !number {
        appendError("should contain at least a single digit")
    }
    if !lower {
        appendError("should contain at least a single lowercase letter")
    }
    if !upper {
        appendError("should contain at least single uppercase letter")
    }

    // if there is any error
    if len(errs) > 0 {
        return false, errs
    }

    // everyting is right
    return true, errs
}
```